# Book identification. Very old Sci-Fi picture book with spaceships traveling in space and taking off from the Earth and strange aliens on other planets

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am looking for an old Sci-Fi picture book I had in the 80s. This book had large color pictures of spaceships traveling in space and taking off from the Earth. Plus it also had pictures of strange aliens on other planets. The format was color pictures and a description of each picture, for example, a huge starship moving through space trailing a large amount of smoke. This was a large book with a dust cover and I loved reading it. But I can not find the name of it.

Comment: This has been asked a few times (including by me) if it is the Terran Trade Authority book that is mentioned. It has been animated here https://vimeo.com/29549708

Comment: There are many books of science fiction art. Can you recall what the dust jacket looked like?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Possibly the [Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD : Terran Trade Authority Handbook](https://www.ebay.com/itm/174783500370?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=174783500370&targetid=1493511275465&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9023178&poi=&campaignid=19851828444&mkgroupid=145880009014&rlsatarget=pla-1493511275465&abcId=9307249&merchantid=8298404&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAw6yuBhDrARIsACf94RU8rqfSL-rbcRaskObkwxRqI5tvS71U45_Mi33qdK_e4Q8b_vCBv0waAjAvEALw_wcB)  from 1978?

From the description:

"The Terran Defense Authority Commander provides information on the design, development, operation, and technical specifications of military, civilian, commercial, and special function spacecraft in use during the twenty-first century".

[image: TTA Handbook Spacecraft]

This was part of a series of books related to speculative fiction including a "travel guide" described in a similar question:

[Interstellar Travel Guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59601/what-is-the-title-of-this-old-interstellar-travel-guide/89796#89796)

As well as TTA books for Space Wrecks, Great Space Battles, etc.

Comment: I looked in the book for pictures with a ship "trailing a large amount of smoke". There were several that could fit that description.

Comment: *Spacecraft* does have a number of pictures of spacecraft trailing smoke (from memory, I think the Minnow does), but is light on aliens.  *Spacewreck* has more planetary scenes, but IIRC is mostly alien flora.  I would actual think of the *Galactic Encounters* books before the *TTA* books, but I don't know them well enough to suggest one from this description.

Comment: Check out the [Space Patrol](http://www.terrantradeauthority.com/galactic-encounters/) book of TTA. Another one in the same series that might match is Aliens in Space.

Comment: The "TTA Spacecraft" book looks influenced- but not drawn by- Chris Foss.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd those books are kind of ad-hoc collections of cover art from various artists thrown together with tacked-on exposition that tries to put them all in a consistent future. I'm pretty sure Foss is represented in them.

Answer (score 10):

Possibly [Space Wars: Worlds and Weapons](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?295155).  Lots of spaceship and some planet-side artwork.

[image: Cover of Space Wars book]