# Looking for an encyclopedia of alien ships from 70s or early 80s

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

We had a large-format hardcover book growing up (in the US in English) that contained illustrations and fictional snippets about alien spacecraft.  It would have been published in the late 70s or early 80s.  The text with each picture contained information regarding the ship like engine manufacturer and other various specs.  I remember the pictures being very well drawn.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked on several occasions. It's an in-universe hardback book called something like "the encyclopedia of known space" or something similar.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - the spacecraft were not from movies or well known.  30 years dulls the memories.  Unfortunately I cannot remember enough to search for them correctly.

Comment: @Valorum - looking for that now, not returning any familiar hits.

Comment: @SDH - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terran_Trade_Authority

Comment: [As usual], @Valorum was right: two questions ([one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59601), [two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49053)). Alas, none have accepted answers.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - And so, so many dead image links.

Comment: @Valorum display fine to me

Comment: @Gallifreyan - That's because you've not found all of the dupes yet. Try seaching for "Terran Trade" (in quotes) in the search bar.

Comment: @Valorum I see. Found only [one with accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7678/what-was-that-sci-fi-book-mixing-classic-art-and-book-excerpts-to-build-a-timeli/7744#7744). Do we dupe in this case?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Yeah. At some point it might be worth improving some of those answers and chasing for acceptances. [Not it](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/community-sitcom/images/c/cc/RCT-Not_it.png/revision/20120915012605).

Answer (score 5):

And of course I found it right after I posted. The book is "Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD" and appears to be related to an RPG. Some of the art is shown [here](http://www.terrantradeauthority.com/tta-books-2/spacecraft-2000-2100-ad/).

[image: Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD book cover]

If anyone enjoys well done spacecraft art, I highly recommend.  It still looks great and brings me back.  If anyone is familiar with the old Battletech technical guide books, this book used the same format with a picture, technical specs, and a short blurb.

Comment: How did you find it? The technique might be useful for future queries.

Comment: FYI, it has a [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?925475) page, which links to the 'RPG's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terran_Trade_Authority)

Comment: @Gallifreyan - nothing special in the search, just '70s book encyclopedia of alien ships'.  I just had to be more patient and keep scrolling down.

Comment: OMG.  I remember this book (and maybe a sequel or related book by same author?) and having it checked out for months from the library and getting an overdue fine for it. So cool!  Too bad we won't have these craft by 2100  https://www.amazon.com/Stewart-Cowley/e/B000AQ471W

Comment: Someone animated it very beautifully: https://vimeo.com/29549708