# Encyclopedia about imagined near-future spacecraft

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book from my childhood (i.e. probably at least 20-30 years old) that was an encyclopedia of imagined near-future spacecraft. It was written as if those craft existed.

This wasn't a work of prose, it was a hardback book in the style of an encyclopedia with lots of illustrations. It could almost be described as a simplistic technical manual of the craft and tools.

It describes spacecraft as they might have been had the Apollo project continued - craft for landing on the moon and starting to build space habitats there.

Can anyone help me identify this please?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153514/looking-for-an-encyclopedia-of-alien-ships-from-70s-or-early-80s - One of these; http://www.digitalwaterfalls.co.uk/ttabooks.html

Comment: The one I'm specifically looking for isn't any of those unfortunately; however I'm a lover of old fictional future works so I will be looking at those, thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This sounds like [The Space Traveller's Handbook: Every Man's Comprehensive Manual To Space flight by Michael Freeman](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3226143-space-traveller-s-handbook).

> *Upholding the great tradition of earthly travel guides, the space
> traveller's handbook is an indispensable companion for visitors to
> take to any part of the Solar System, whether tourist, hard hat
> construction worker or space colonist. Written from the perspective of
> 100 years after the first manned orbit it gives an all-embracing view
> of space flight, covering not only the sights of the Solar System, but
> also the practical mechanics of rocketry and the training necessary
> for travelers*
>
> <sub><sup>[Biblio - Southern Books](https://biblio.co.uk/space-travellers-handbook-by-freeman-michael/work/480884)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in a short review I found

Comment: Yes! That's the one, thank you so much! I couldn't find many images of the inside of the book online: here's one: http://easterfairwether.nl/BillEaster2015/infography.html

Comment: That's only 43 years away. We better get started if we are going to make that deadline.

Answer (score 9):

Another one in a similar vein is [*Spacecraft 2000 to 2100 AD*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spacecraft-2000-2100-D-Stewart-Cowley/dp/0890092117) published by the "Terran Defence Authority".

> The Terran Defense Authority Commander provides information on the design, development, operation, and technical specifications of military, civilian, commercial, and special function spacecraft in use during the twenty-first century

However, [one of the reviews](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-reviews/R334HBDYMQOHEV/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0890092117) mentions that there were also short stories in this book.

> Another excellent book from the TTA Handbook Series. I remember this title as part of a series of hardback editions from the late 1970s and early 1980s. The marriage of the images/colour plates of Spacecraft 2000-2100, A.D. with various short stories, which were tailored around them, was very enthralling and highly imaginative.

[image: Front cover]

Comment: A very good book, but probably not the answer. Not a tech manual, more like a recognition handbook.